# Selecting element with multiple classes in Capybara

Tags: selenium, capybara

I'm writing automation code in Capybara with Selenium.
I have the following element in my HTML, and I wanna click this element in Capybara.

```
<a href="#" class="classA classB">click me</a>
```

At the moment, the way worked is something like following.

```
find('.classA', :text=>"click me").click
```

But I wanna select the element from the names of the two classes like this

```
find('a.classA.classB').click
click_on('a.classA.classB')
```

I know we can get javascript code fired, but this is not smart.

```
page.execute_script('$("a.classA.classB").click()')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can search an element by `xpath`

based on your example, seems like the following should work

```
//div[contains(@class, 'classA') and contains(@class, 'classB')]
```

You could also use `css`

```
(:css, ".classA.classB")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still getting the same error.

Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button "//*[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),'classA') and (contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),'classB')) ]"

Comment: @Ryo, made an edit, try that out. If that doesn work we can try some thing else.

Comment: Thank you!The second one worked, actually I did like this find(:css, ".classA.classB", :visible=>true).click

Comment: @Ryo, Great!! Just in case you have time and are as curios as me, can you check for the first option as well?