# Unable to click on Save button using By.className while className available in div

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to click on Save button using `By.className` while `classNam`e available in 
webpage code for button available

```
<div class="popupFooter">
<div align="center">
<input id="Preview-btn" class="btn-primary previewDetaile" type="button" value="Preview">
<input class="btn-primary validateProfile" type="button" value="Save">
<input id="clear" class="btn-primary" type="button" value="Cancel">
</div></div>
```

Selenium Code

```
 driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary validateProfile")).click();
```

Problem:
Unable to click on Save button

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Arran wild guess would be `InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names are not supported.`

Comment: @ErkiM. good point - unfortunately it's questions like this, "This doesnt work" that leaves you asking *more* questions for the OP!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you search for multiple classnames which does not work with `By.className`. Just try

```java
driver.findElement(By.className("validateProfile")).click();
```

instead. For selecting elements by multiple classnames you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15837464/2756574).

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy with a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector(".btn-primary.validateProfile")
).click();
```

For a full reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

As @Sebastian pointed out, it's probably due to the fact that `By.className` accepts only one class name (I think it's not by chance that they didn't name it `By.classNames` :) )