# How to exclude particular class/atrribute name in CSS selector in Selenium Automation?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I have below HTML sample code:

```
<a href="" title="Design" class="reMode_design  reMode_hover">
    <span>Design</span>
</a>

<a href="" title="Design" 
 class="reMode_design  reMode_hover reMode_selected">
    <span>Design</span>
</a>
```

Here, i need to define CSS for the 1st href element and want to ignore 2nd element which has this class "reMode_selected". How to define css for the 1st element by ignoring 2nd element???

I don't want to use Xpath and I am looking for like this below CSS selector:

```
element :fld_link, "[title='Design'] [class !='reMode_selected']"
```

This format doesn't work in SitePrism Cucumber.  Need Help on how to exclude a attribute name in CSS selector...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `cssSelector`

```
driver.find_element(:css,".reMode_design:not(.reMode_selected)")
```

Comment: I didn't try that code yet. But i will let you know and accept the answer if that works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do with this css locator    `a[title='Design']:not([class*='reMode_selected'])`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an xpath to locate the element? Perhaps something like: `//a[contains(@title, 'Design') and not(contains(@class, 'reMode_selected'))]`

References/Examples:

[Using `not` in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550981/how-to-use-not-in-xpath)

[Using `and` in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837151/selecting-element-with-multiple-classes-in-capybara)

Comment: I don't want to use xpath. I forgot to mention. If its there any way i can use css instead your given xpath ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not:` css prefix as others have mentioned or you could combine a capybara query to return the element based off it's text, or use a waiter.

SitePrism is quite advanced, so pretty much all options are open to you